# DOS batch - I need extensive debug output

Tags: dos, batch-file

I got an annoying issue here.
My build system uses some DOS batch snippets in the building process and they are in some cases very complex.

I have an error where the task simply aborts with no error at all -.-

I do recall to have read in the internet that the output can be extended somehow.
I think it was something with enabling extensions or so.

Does someone know what I exactly am looking for? A research in the net went pretty south as I can't find uniqe key words for a search.

Cheers
Jan

Answer (score 1):

This might not be completely helpful, but if you have "echo off" (multiple instances) in your script, reset that to "echo on". Redirect the stdout to a file to search easily.

Also, if there are any "exit" statements at intermediate steps, change them to "exit /b" (and change "exit " to "exit /b ") so that only that batch file exits (but not the cmd.exe instance).

Thanks!

Parag Doke

Comment: I am working with these steps but I am looking for in detail information what a command does and why.
Especially when working with nested conditions and using string manipulation may this become a hassle.

The script is verifying upfront if the sysntax is OK and if the variables have will have values. If not it breaks with some obscure error or simply exists without any statement. Neither echo on nor exit will help you out of this situation :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this time by copying the script to a batch file, deleted everything except first condition and then started to add logic content subsequently each time a run was successful.
After that did I feed the logical elements with the actions they are supposed to do.

That did the trick to find the bug(s) but that took me pretty much time as the scripts partially are several 100 lines and as mentioned before pretty complex.

Comment: I have seen in conjunction with string manipulation a trick how to get full detailed information what is going on.

I would still highly appreciate if someone should know what I am looking for and post it here :)

Cheers